# Strong gas smell when first turning on oven

Tags: gas, oven, natural-gas

has anyone dealt with a very strong gas smell when you are first turning on a gas oven?

We purchased a Kucht KNG361 gas range last year and each time we turn on the oven, a stronger than usual gas smell ensues for about 10 minutes while it is first heating up. There is NO gas smell while the oven is off.

We have double checked all of the gas connections to ensure they meet the install requirements for that range:

https://kucht.com/online/product/model-kng361-color/

We called the company who installed the oven and they tested the lines leading into the oven twice and confirmed no gas leakage. Their prognosis was that it is somewhat common to have a gas smell when first turning on the gas stove and due to the size of this particular unit (5.2 CU ft) it will be more pervasive since the inside cavity first must fill with a significant amount of gas before the pilot light turns on.

We called the manufacturer who also confirms the same thing.

We’re one year in to owning and using the oven but still struggle with the gas smell (only when first turning on the oven, not after it’s been running or with the top burners). We have a vent hood with fans that we turn on as well as a window nearby which we crack open while first turning on the oven.

That somewhat helps but still is not enough. I’m mildly annoyed as I can smell it temporarily, however my partner gets a bad headache and has to stop whatever she is doing, leave the room, and lay down due to the gas smell.

Has anyone worked with a fire department to run some sort of gas level detection test or anything similar?

Short of replacing the gas range or switching to electric/induction, does anyone have any other advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Your local fire department will be happy to come and check it out.  Unfortunately different people have different sensitivities to smell.  One person will be oh stinky, let's eat, while the person beside them will be passing out.  I imagine the flames are nice and blue when burning and you have a CO detector.  Due to your partner, it might be better to get rid of gas, since it seems to affect their health

Comment: If the manufacturer says this is normal, I don't know that there's much you can do. Unfortunately, you may need to switch to a different model or brand that doesn't emit quite so much gas before lighting, or switch (unfortunately) to electric.

Comment: The residental model gas ranges I have seen recently use electricity for the oven (marketing term is dual fuel). Does your oven have electric controls for timing etc.? In the past I have used older natural gas fired ovens and do not recall any gas smell on startup. Either your oven is a poor design or it is out of adjustment or has a non performing part.

Comment: My new range (the same exact model as yours) does the same thing. I called the gas company to come and test with their odor-meter and it went off as soon as I turned on the oven. They wanted to pull my gas meter but the gas dissipated in a few minutes (with the hood fan on and the convection fan on). I also had my gas lines checked twice. I am of the belief that all the bigger, newer ovens do this. I replaced a 6 month old 5.2 cu ft. Mueller range (the oven quit working completely) that did the same thing. Seems kind of dangerous because the gas smell is so strong. I just make sure I don't lig

Comment: The OP's opinion that the large size of the oven is responsible for the gas smell at startup requiring a large volume to fill up with gas cannot possibly be the explanation. Such a condition would lead to an explosion when  the flame would be initiated. There is some peculiarity of this oven design that is causing a small release of gas that is dissipating (rather than collecting) leading to the spread of dilute gas. I doubt this is a hazardous condition but it is nevertheless irritating to the point of being unacceptable. I think you should seek to return the appliance.

Comment: Every gas oven I've ever used created a substantial gas smell when firing up.

Comment: Thanks all, I have been slacking on updating this. We did have the fire dept come out and do a reading. No gas detected while oven is off, but a very minor level was detected when first turn on, far below the threshold of what is considered dangerous. Their takeaway was that while there is a small amount of CO2 detected when starting the range, it’s well under the danger level and somewhat normal for a large gas range. They did recommend we could run the convection fan while it’s heating up which has helped a bit with my partner’s reaction to the odor.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, CNG has no smell. Gas companies add chemicals such as mercaptan to make it smell, for safety.

Just because you can smell it when you are starting it, does not make it dangerous. If you cant smell it when the oven is off and you can't snell it when the oven is operational, and there is no explision when you switch it on, there is nothing to be worried about.